# Weird behaviour for python cookies, unable to set cookies

Tags: python, cookies, http-headers, setcookie, nameko

I am using Python Nameko as my microservice framework, and when I try to set cookies in my get request, I can't seems to do it, below is my code:

```
from http import cookies
from nameko.web.handlers import http

@http('GET', '/hello')
    def say_hello(self, request):
        c = cookies.SimpleCookie()
        c['test-cookie'] = 'test-1'
        return 200, c, 'Hello World!'
```

When I call the get request using Postman, below is what I get back from the request:
[image]

Anyone can help in understanding the behaviour?
Instead of Set-Cookie ->, it's  ->, as shown in the image.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://nameko.readthedocs.io/en/stable/built_in_extensions.html#http), the 3-tuple response type for `nameko.http` is `(status_code, headers dict, response body)`. That is, the second argument is a dict of headers, which is not the same as a cookie object

To set cookies you need to construct an instance of [`werkzeug.wrappers.Response`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.Response) yourself (also included in that list in the docs):

```
    @http('GET', '/hello')
    def say_hello(self, request):
        response = Response("Hello World!")
        response.set_cookie('test-cookie', 'test-1')
        return response
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @second, I tried to use the wrapper you suggested, but I only get this: Error: TypeError: Payload must be a string. Got `None`, when I use the wrapper with .set_cookie function.

Comment: sounds like it might be something specific to what you are doing. maybe post a new question with a _runnable_ (but minimal) code example that shows the issue

Comment: Hi second, it's all fine when I do response = Response("Hello World!", 200), followed by set cookie. Felt like it's a bug or something